# How to map ISO dates to Date objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to map an array of ISO dates and I thought I could to this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const times = ["2021-01-26T17:00:00.000Z", "2021-01-26T17:00:00.000Z"];
  const formattedTimes = times.map((time) => new Date(time));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {formattedTimes.map((time) => (
        <h2>{time}</h2>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

but this causes an error: Here is the sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-hill-x18ws?file=/src/App.js:0-346)

> "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Wed Jan 27 2021
> 01:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: This code most certainly doesn't produce that error. It must be something later where you use `formattedTimes`.

Comment: How are you using formattedTimes?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev - the error indicates a JSX renderer.

Comment: I guess you want to render it to the dom

Comment: Will need to see the render code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to loop through `formattedTimes` array. But that is the array of objects, so you need to call `toString` method.

```
<div>{
 formattedTimes.map(formatted => <span>{formatted.toString()}</span>)
}<div>
```